# Testing Nested Asynchronous functions using jest

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of code

```
this.app.get('/cars/carname/:carname', function (request, response) {
            let carname = request.params.carname;
            this.database.collection('carkart').find({ "carname": carname }).toArray(function (err, docs) {
                result = JSON.stringify(docs);
            });
          response.send(result);
        });
```

I have written jest testcases for app.get but how to write test cases for internal functions like `response.send` and `database.collection.find` so that 100% code coverage can be achieved?

Comment: this.app.get('/cars/carname/:carname', function (request, response)                    { let carname = request.params.carname;       this.database.collection('carkart').find({ "carname": carname }).toArray(function (err, docs) { result = JSON.stringify(docs); });                           response.send(result); });

Comment: If possible give a sample code with example